# System does not fully support snapd: The "fuse" filesystem is required on this system but not available

Tags: 18.04, snap, gnu, fuse

As the title implies, I can not use snap as the fuse filesystem ist not fully supported.

I don't know what the fuse filesystem is and **why it seems that I'm the only one with this problem** on a newly installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0 x86_64) machine.

*And it seems that snap is not shipped with my version as other sources are saying ("This packaging system, available on Ubuntu 18.04 by default..." [sauce](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-nextcloud-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-1-%E2%80%93-installing-nextcloud))*

The full error message:

> system does not fully support snapd: The "fuse" filesystem is required on this system but not available. Please try to install the fuse package.

Comment: I must post thath for others who have this same issue, I need use useflags sudo USE="apparmor" emerge -av1 snapd missing aparmor cause my problem.
probably modprobe loop was also needed, but i am not sure if last command made snap working.

Comment: No, unfortunately rebooting system, I come back to that problem. modprobe loop is not helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

You just need to install the fuse package... as it says.

```
sudo apt-get install fuse
```

Source: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/fuse